# on a different page onclick or run javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, href

I want to run javascript or click a element on the page I access with google extension

```
<a href="javascript: void(0);" class="fright">
```

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) - Your question is very vague. Please explain the use case

Comment: You mean `document.querySelector(".fright").click()` ?

Answer (score 0):

You mean

```
document.querySelector(".fright").click()
```